# Python 3.x Homework help. Sequential number guessing game.

Tags: python-3.x, random, module

We are supposed to make a number guessing game where depending on what difficulty the player chooses the game generates 4 or 5 numbers and the player is given all but the last, which they have to guess in 3 tries. The numbers have to be equal distances apart, and the numbers have to be within the 1 - 100 range.

So far I know what it will look like roughly.

```
def guesses:
    function for accumulating tries as long as guesses_taken < 3
    let user retry, or congratulate and offer to replay

def game_easy:
    code for number generation, step value, etc
    guesses()

def game_hard:
    same code as easy mode, with the appropriate changes
    guesses()
```

For the random numbers, all I have so far is this

```
guess_init = rand.int (1,100)
step = rand.int (1,20)
guess_init = guess_init + step
```

and just having it loop and add the step 4 or 5 times respectively.

Where I'm stuck is 1. How to ensure that none of the numbers generated exceed 100 (so it can't be a step of 1 starting at 98), and 2. how to print all but the last number generated.

What I was thinking was assigning the last number generated to a variable that the player input must match. But I was also thinking that if "guess_init" has ran through the loop, then it will already be holding the value of the last number and all Ill have to check is that user input == guess_init.

Answer (score 0):

In your Case you should read the [random section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) from the Python Standard Library. Especially this is relevant:

```
random.randrange(start, stop[, step])
Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step). This is equivalent to choice(range(start, stop, step)), but doesn’t actually build a range object.
```

Comment: randrange looks like it may work, but how do I limit it to generating only 4 numbers between 1 and 100, and is it possible to make the step number a random number between 1 and 20?

the only way I can think to help is to throw something dealing with lists in, but my teacher discourages it as we haven't gotten that far and wants us to try and use only things we've learned so far in class.

Comment: You have to solve your homework yourself, so that you can experience the insights yourself. If you should not use lists, you can use a for loop: `n = 4` `step = randint(1, 20)` `for i in range(n): guess_init = choice(range(start, stop, step))`

Comment: where exactly is the point if you know 3 of 4 numbers that have the same distance to each other and to guess the number 4? Example: I know 16, 24, 32 and I should guess the 4th number? Surprise: 40